# How can I call models and helpers in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1.7

In magento 1 if we want to call a helper or a model we can do like below if we use `Mage::app();`

```
Mage::all();
$exampleModel1 = new Company_Module_Model_Example;
```

if we add a config file we can use like below

```
$exampleModel = Mage::getModel("model/test");
$example helper = Mage::helper("helper/test");
```

> How can I do those things in Magento 2

Comment: Where  you want to call model and helper ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In magento 2 this is done with dependency injection. Classes are added as dependencies to classes in the `__construct` method. For instance if you have a block class and you want to add your helper and/or model classes it would look something like this:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class CustomBlock extends Template
{
    protected $myHelper;

    protected $myModel;

    public function __construct(
        \Vendor\Module\Model\MyModel $myModel,
        \Veddor\Module\Helper\MyHelper $myHelper,
        Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->myModel = $myModel;
        $this->myHelper = $myHelper;
    }
}
```

You can now use the helper or model anywhere in your block class by calling `$this->myHelper` or `$this->myModel`. It's important to note that this is the Magento 1 equivalent to `Mage::getSingleton` by default and you should use factory classes where you when you want to ensure you are getting a new instance of a class. An example could be changing the model instance in the above example to a factory:

```
protected $myModelFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Vendor\Module\Model\MyModelFactory $myModelFactory,
    \Veddor\Module\Helper\MyHelper $myHelper,
    Template\Context $context,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->myModelFactory = $myModelFactory;
    $this->myHelper = $myHelper;
}
```

Now instead of using `$this->myModel` to get the singleton, you will instantiate a new instance of your model with something like:
`$myModel = $this->myModelFactory->create();`

Alan Storm wrote a great primer on modern DI, Magento's ObjectManager class (and why you should never use it directly), and Magento 2's approach to DI http://alanstorm.com/magento2_dependency_injection_2015/

Comment: Do i need to use config.xml file then at what time i nedd to use that

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Automatic constructor Injection` to access desired class object in your current class. like below:

```
public function __construct(
    \Company\Module\Model\Example $exampleModel
    \Company\Module\Helper\Data $exampleHelper
) {    
    $this->exampleModel             = $exampleModel;
    $this->exampleHelper            = $exampleHelper;
}
```

You can read more about this from [Devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html)

**EDIT**

Step 1: Add the Helper Class in __construct as above

Step 2: Using this `$this->exampleHelper->functionName()` you can call Helper function in execute and other methods of controller

Comment: Do i need to use config.xml file then at what time i nedd to use that

Comment: No you can directly use the helper and model using the above way, Without specifying in XML file and in Magento 2 there is no config.xml in module

Comment: Thank you, if there is a method in helper that i need to get to the controller how can i do that, im new to magento 2 and try to learn it correct way

Comment: I have updated my answer. hope it will help you